# Starting with NFC and Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, nfc, android-wireless

I am very new to NFC but good hands on Android. I had found some definition of it on StackOverflow, Google and Wikipedia. I have downloaded the Android SDK for NFC.
I have few queries in mind that couldn't be solved after a lot of googling

- What is difference between NFC and other Wireless(Bluetooth WiFi)
- I have HTC Phone with me and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NFC_enabled_handsets), I found that my phone doesn't support NFC. Can I use NFC SDK for Android that can act as NFC phone?
- There is concept of tag in NFC, I didn't get that.
- What NFC gives us? I mean is it coding API, a library?
- What can I do to make my mobile NFC enable?

Any one who had worked on NFC.For a beginner these questions are very important to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC is a very close distance wireless communication (less than 2 centimeters) and cannot be compared to Bluetooth or WiFi as it's speed is much worse - so it's not suitable for transmitting massive amounts of data.

To use NFC your phone needs a NFC chip which has a tiny internal antenna that is able to receive NFC signals from corresponding tags (actually your phone even gives these tags energy). So the tag is just a tiny chip without own energy resources (at least the passive ones) which enable to store some data (often less than 1kb).

NFC is used to enable secure data transfer like paying with a credit card or some other usecases.

Sadly there is no way to just enable NFC on your phone - there are some external NFC kits which may work via USB but those are not offically supported - so you'd have to buy a new phone for that (like the new HTC or Samsung ones).

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: Thanks alot for kind response.Can I use the SDK for Android ? instead of using new phone?

Comment: Of course you can implement an application that utilizes NFC - but it won't work on your phone.

Comment: The Android emulator that comes with the SDK does not emulate NFC

Comment: Right - it just can't. @Mentor - please accept the answer if it was fitting enough for you - this is an act to acknowledge the poster's work.

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt I want to ask that can i test a NFC application on emulator on windows I mean NFC emulator for android

Comment: @NFCguy  I want to ask that can i test a NFC application on emulator on windows I mean NFC emulator for android

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @NFCguy I mean My phone doesn't support NFC,if I create NFC APp how can I test it in windows? DOES ANdroid SDK supports that?

Comment: @Mentor - there is NO way to test it in the emulator yet. You need to buy an Android device with NFC.

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt then why we have nfc sdk,please see this http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/

Comment: @Mentor I didn't know that addon. Try it and develop ;-) Still your hardware device needs a NFC chip to work - so it'll be only an emulation on the AVD (Android Virtual Device).